# OpenSource web based documentation system

Tags: html, documentation

I have a set of HTML pages that document my (OpenSource) software which looks fine in any browser. Now I'd like to help the user searching through the documentation (full text search, some keyword indexing). Is there a small, OpenSource, framework that allows me to a) keep my web pages but adds some API for indexing / full text search? Preferable only using `nodejs`?

Answer (score 1):

[Meteor](http://meteor.com) is worth considering, it is an ultra-simple environment for building modern web applications.

With Meteor you write apps:

- in pure Javascript
- that send data over the wire, rather than HTML
- using your choice of popular open-source libraries

Documentation is available at http://docs.meteor.com/

---

Windows support will most likely come with version 0.6.18 of node.js, it does support Linux & OS X.

Comment: I've seen an impressive video on meteor these days (probably on their web page). I didn't think of using it for documentation purpose, but that's a nice idea. I need it cross platform, but if not "all" are supported right now, that's not a problem. Great Idea, thanks!

Comment: @Patrick: I believe node.js will release their next version around next week. I'm actually running Meteor on Windows right now (using a compiled version of node.js and various fixes) and will do pull requests once the next version is there, such that everyone can benefit. :)